# checking if params exists in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

This is what I'd like to do:

I have this piece of code:

```
customer = Customer.find(:first, :conditions => {:siteId => params[:siteId], :customerCode => params[:id]})
```

If :customerCode is null, I'd like to use :temporaryCode instead. But I don't know how.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if (params[:id])` to check to param `id` exists or not.

Comment: you use params[:id] in customercode if params id is null then what would you use instead of params[:id] for temporarycode?

Comment: @xdazz: `params.has_key? :id` would be better since that is exactly what you mean.

Comment: @muistooshort Won't `if (params[:id])` be enough in most situations?

Comment: @xdazz: There is a possibility that someone is preprocessing `params` so `nil` could be a valid value for `params[:id]`. I think it is best to say exactly what you mean rather than making assumptions.

Comment: @muistooshort Yep, You're right :)

Comment: @muistooshort can you elaborate further about params.has_key? :id? I'm new to that concept. Thank you. If you can give me an example that would really be great.

Comment: [`Hash#has_key?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F) returns `true` if the Hash has the key you're asking about and `false` otherwise. I don't think that's what you're looking for here though, you seem to want to use a different column in the database if `customercode` is NULL, you'd use `has_key?` to ask `params` if it contains a certain key.

Comment: @xdazz: I think they want to use `:customerCode` if that column isn't NULL and `:temporaryCode` if `:customerCode` is NULL.

Comment: @muistooshort yes, actually that's what i'm really looking for. I'm testing the answer you gave me right now

Answer (score 1):

```
customer   = Customer.find_by_siteid_and_customercode  params[:siteId], params[:id]
customer ||= Customer.find_by_siteid_and_temporarycode params[:siteId], params[:id]
```

making use of finders is most safer, cleaner

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want to use COALESCE inside the database:

```
customer = Customer.where(:siteId => params[:siteId])
                   .where('coalesce(customercode, temporarycode) = ?', params[:id])
                   .first
```

The SQL COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that isn't NULL. For example:

```
coalesce(column1, column2)
```

gives you `column1` if `column1` isn't NULL and `column2` if `column1` is NULL.

---

If you're using Rails2 then something like this should work:

```
Customer.find(:first, :conditions => [
    'siteid = ? and coalesce(customercode, temporarycode) = ?',
    params[:siteId], params[:id]
])
```

Comment: @Sagiv: true but that's a pretty safe assumption unless stated otherwise.

Comment: the .where is not available in rails 2. So i tried this instead:

Comment: @AldrinDelaCruz: I added a Rails2 option, you should indicate in your question that you're using Rails2 now that it is getting rather old.